# What's a word that means "quickly" and "easily"?

Tags: word-choice

The current sentence is: "While this can be interpreted as a response to World War II, it can also be seen as an analysis - a depiction of how fragile society actually is, and how easily it can be disrupted." However, I want to change the word "easily" in the last part of it to a word that means both "quick" and "easy." Of course, now that I need a word that covers both of those meanings, I can't think of one!

Comment: 'Readily' overlaps with both [[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/readily): 'quickly and easily'], but 'how rapidly and how easily' sounds far better here.

Answer (score 1):

After consulting several reverse dictionaries and thesaurus.com, here is what I found (all definitions off Merriam-Webster):

1. **Readily**

> a: without hesitating. b: without much difficulty

2. **Effortlessly**

> showing or requiring little or no difficulty

3. **Facilely**

> a: easily accomplished or attained. b: used or comprehended with ease.

4. **Agilely**

> marked by ready ability to move with quick easy grace